# Finding faces of volume enclosed by planes

Tags: algorithm, geometry, volume

Ultimately, I want to implement an algorithm with the following specifications:

**Input:** *N* planes in 3 dimensions (Ax + By + Cz = D given for each plane)

**Output:**

1. A list *V* of vertices, and
2. A list *E* of edges (pairs from *V*), and
3. A list *F* of faces (cycles from *E*) that precisely bound the volume enclosed (that is, on the opposite side of the normals) by the *N* planes

It is not guaranteed that each plane will coincide with a face, but it is guaranteed that the volume always unambiguously exists (i.e. the planes have well-behaved normals).

I know this is in the realm of computational geometry, but I've tried Googling some of the terms above and I haven't found anything. I think a solution ought to include a binary space partition tree.

So far I've tried the naive method - just making a huge N^2 (ish) list of all slices between the planes, and then checking each slice against each plane, and removing those that are on the wrong side of at least one plane. This is N^3 and of course inefficient, and it doesn't even give the edges yet - you still have to compute where the start- and endpoints of the edges are on the slices.

Any help pointing to algorithms in CG would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Notice that a given set of planes might enclose several different volumes.  Finding vertices, edges, and faces of the volume containing the origin in its interior is the dual of a 3-dimensional convex hull problem; map the plane Ax+By+Cz=1 to the point (A,B,C).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hook to the convex hull problem, I'll look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an O(n log n)-time algorithm due to [Preparata and Muller, 1979](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900550). It uses polar duality together with an efficient 3D convex hull algorithm. I'm sure that there exist implementations of it (qhull maybe?).

Comment: Thank you, this is either what I want or close to it!

Comment: There is an implementation in [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) introduced in the 4.6 release. See [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/group__PkgConvexHull3Functions.html#ga9cd990d6e33e680b0961370c09782671) and [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/group__PkgConvexHull3Functions.html#gabd45c50c35eb122ecb88a044988a4743)